# Postgres 8 support with Django 1.8

Tags: django, postgresql

I am upgrading Django from 1.5 to 1.8.

My production server is running postgres 8.4.20 but Django 1.8 says it dropped support for Postgres <= 9.0.

If I go ahead and upgrade, is it likely to still work or will it fail in some spectacular way?

If it's going to fail, I need to consider the implications of upgrading postgres before I carry on.

Comment: If I were you, I'd upgrade postgres by creating a basebackup and restoring the data. With PostgreSQL 9.5< you get a lot of features for point in time recovery and live migrations. Towards your questions I don't know what's going to happen or not happen.

Comment: Postgres 8.4 is so old, I barely remember it! ;-)
You should consider upgrading just for security reasons, but, if you need another reason, remember performance are better with each new PostgreSQL version!

Comment: Not supported means not supporting, may be all runs until it fails unexpected way. Just upgrade man. You can ;)

Comment: @ThomasSchwärzl pg_basebackup appeared in version 9.1... The better way to do it would be to use a logical backup (pg_dump/pg_restore), or else you would have to upgrade to each major version from 8.4 to 9.6... That's a long way!

Comment: @Arkhena ou, missed that one. Thanks!

Comment: @Arkhena: [pg_upgrade](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html) can upgrade a cluster directly from 8.4 to 9.6

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh you're right! Great! I learnt something! :-)